# Displaying only the part of the line of txt file

Tags: java, android

I have a txt file with 200.000 lines. I want to show in AutoCompleteTextView only city name and country. I have idea (Show only characters) How to do that?

Example of line: (4463523   Denver  35.531250   -81.029800  US).
In this example i want to show Denver and US.

Comment: Use a `regex` with `replaceAll`

Answer (score 0):

Well, unfortunately, there will not be a good way except reading the whole file in (use, for example, a `Scanner`). Then you can, for example, store the parts you want to access quickly in a `HashMap`. Depends on your specific usecase and how much memory/cpu time you want to spend.

Comment: Can you explain me better please?

Comment: What did you try til now? You will have to read the data into memory, for this I suggest using a `Scanner`. You will find enough tutorials, etc. for that around.It seems that parsing your data is simply a case of String.split(" "); . I do not intend to write the code for you, but if you have specific problems, feel free to ask.